# Use a color to create an alpha channel for a PNG?

Tags: python, image, transparency, python-imaging-library

I have several images that claim to have a transparent background but are actually white. I'd like to use Python Image Library/PIL to set that white background color to actually be transparent.

Since PNG uses an alpha channel, I'd love to create the alpha channel by finding contiguous areas of white from the edges of the image (so I don't get "holes" of transparency when the image contains white data).

Any tips on how to create the alpha channel this way?

Comment: You'd need a flood fill and you'd have to be cute about how you apply it. Would you want to handle "land-locked" white areas in the middle of a side? Anyway, this won't work if the images have any partial transparency. Can you not solve the actual problem and get proper alpha into the source images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I'd guess you'd want to run across the image in a spiral from the outside, setting a pixel to transparent if it is white, and a pixel further towards the edge is <s>also white</s> transparent. Stop once you've done a whole circle without changing any pixels.</s>

Shouldn't be too difficult to write such a loop.

Do some kind of [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), seeded from the white edge pixels.

Comment: You'd have to do it to a back buffer first. And you'd need to find a path right to the edge, just one pixel isn't the right test.

Comment: @David Heffernan - That's why you start from the edge.

Comment: @Orange The edit makes it better, but you'd still need a transparent path all the way to the edge. Why wouldn't you just do flood fill in the standard recursive way? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: @David Heffernan - It's not a flood fill. It's a set all white areas next to the edge to transparent assuming there is no transparency already in the image.

Comment: @David Heffernan - If the OP wants to do a flood fill they can, but you need a first pass to find the correct seed points.

Comment: @David Heffernan - Having a transparent pixel closer to the edge guarantees a path to the edge, by construction.

Comment: @David Heffernan - Ah, so it is.

Comment: @David - Thanks for the example, I thought you were too :p

Comment: +1 in compensation for the bitter after taste of humble pie!!

Comment: These are aerial images and I want "islands" of white to actually be white (not transparent), so flood fill from the edge is what I'm looking for. I was hoping PIL had something like this already, but I'm happy to implement it. Thanks for the pointers, all.